# Cambiar color de input select disable

Tags: html, css, select, input

espero puedan ayudarme con este pequeño problema que se me presenta.

Tengo un formulario y dentro de el hay 3 input select. Los input text tienen placeholders y lo que me están solicitando es que el color de los input select salga del mismo color que los placeholders (gris).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa es que sólo necesito que se cambie el color de la primera opción y no de todos los options. Es decir que no suceda esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías aprovecharte de la especifidad **CSS** para conseguir lo que quieres. Efectivamente si le cambias el color a un `<select>` todos los `<option>` que lo tengan como padre, van a heredar dicho cambio. Por eso, si tan solo quieres que el cambio de color afecte al `<select>` sin desplegar, puedes darle el color gris al `<select>` y después el color que quieres con el que salgan los `<option>` del desplegable dárselo a los `<option>` del `<select>`.

```css
#mi-select {
  color: grey;
}

#mi-select option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="mi-select">
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
  <option value="3">Tres</option>
  <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
</select>
```